# Rest framework django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Boa noite, estava estudando um pouco de rest framework no django e desenvolvi uma api simples para consumir com o Angular deu tudo certo porém a minha api que eu fiz é limitada a

```
{ 
  [
    {
      "id":1,
      "name":"lima",
      "phone","000000000",
      "email","dsasdasd@gmail.com",
      "photo","localhost/members/profile/foto1.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id":2,
      "name":"Carlos",
      "phone","000000000",
      "email","dadsa@gmail.com",
      "photo","localhost/members/profile/foto2.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

Ela era limitada a essa estrutura json porém eu queria fazer algo mais completo e um pouco mais complexo kk vou dar um exemplo aqui de como eu queria:

```
{
   [
      "id": 1,

      "User": {

         "name":"João Vitor",

         "phone":"000000000",

         "email": "dadjiadad@gmail.com",
         "configuracoes": {
               "aqui vem algumas configurações setadas pelo usuário 
         }

     },

     "pedidos": [

          {

             "Aqui vem uma lista de pedidos desse usuário que vai chegar através de outra aplicação
          }
     ]
   ]
}
```

Consumir a e manipular a api usando o Angular eu to conseguindo de boa o problema ta sendo em como eu vou criar essa api mais complexa ai. Vou deixar o aquivo de model onde eu descrevo a minha api e depois faço o migrate desse arquivo.

Esse é o arquivo de migrate 0001

```
# Generated by Django 3.0.6 on 2020-05-28 14:57

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Member',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('surname', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('phone', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('email', models.EmailField(max_length=254)),
                ('addres', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('photo', models.ImageField(upload_to='members_profile')),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

E esse é o model que gerou esse arquivo:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Member(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()
    addres = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='members_profile', blank=True, null=True )

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} {self.surname}'
```

Comment: Olá viva. Partilha os models que estás a utilizar que precisas para a tua api terás um objeto member outro user e por fim configuracoes? Outra coisa, elimina o migrations, não tendo nenhum erro associado, não é relevante apresentares aqui, não acrescenta valor à tua questão. Outra coisa que fiquei com a impressão, posso estar enganado, é que desenvolveste o client e agora estás no backend, dá uma vista de olhos no conceito api-first https://dzone.com/articles/an-api-first-development-approach-1. É possivel obter a api como queres, mas terá de ser criado a estrutura de dados correta (models).

Answer (score 1):

A estrutura que você deseja retornar não corresponde as boas práticas (acredito que seja até inviável), até onde eu entendi é uma lista que tem um char, um objeto e uma outra lista de sets.

A solução que eu irei informar é uma lista de objetos onde nesse objeto irá ter um id, o objeto do usuário e a lista de pedidos.

Uma solução que facilitaria a construção dessa estrutura seria utilizar o **SerializerMethodField**, esse atributo funciona a gente definir o retorno de um determinado campo a partir de um metodo no nosso serializer.

Segue o serializer para a estrutura que mencionei:

```
class UsuarioSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    phone = serializers.CharField()
    email = serializers.CharField()
    configuracoes = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_configuracoes(self, objeto):
        configuracoes_usuario = ... #Filter ou alguma forma de associar as configurações ao objeto usuario.

        return configuracoes_usuario # Retorna uma lista ou dicionario de configuracoes

class InterfaceComplexaSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    User = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    pedidos = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_User(self, objeto):
        serializer_usuario = UsuarioSerializer(objeto)

        return serializer_usuario.data

    def get_pedidos(self, objeto):
        lista_pedidos = ... #Um filter ou alguma forma de associar os pedidos ao objeto usuario.

        return lista_pedidos


...: meu_serializer = InterfaceComplexaSerializer( 
...:    [ 
...:        objeto_usuario1, 
...:        objeto_usuario2, 
...:        objeto_usuario3 
...:    ],
...:    many=True
...:)

...: print(meu_serializer.data)
```

Resultado Final:

```
>   [
...:   {
...:      "id": 1,
...:      "User": {
...:         "name":"João Vitor",
...:         "phone":"000000000",
...:         "email": "dadjiadad@gmail.com",
...:         "configuracoes": {
...:            "config1": "teste",
...:            "config2": "teste2",
...:            "config3": "test3"
...:         }
...:     },
...:     "pedidos": [
...:        "Aqui vem uma lista de pedidos desse usuário que vai chegar através de outra aplicação",
...:        "Outra mensagem",
...:        "Outra mensage2"
...:     ]
...:   }
...:   ...
...:]
```

**Importante**:
O único problema que você tem que se atentar é que a cada objeto usuário, os metódos "get_configuracoes", "get_User" e "get_pedidos" irá ser executado. Ou seja, se em get_configuracoes tiver uma busca com o filter do models, e eu passar 10 objetos usuários para o "InterfaceComplexaSerializer" irá ser feito 10 hits/queries para o banco de dados.

Answer (score 0):

Para ter algo mais completo e complexo, como você disse, é preciso criar um campo do tipo ManyToManyField no seu Model. Exemplo:

```
from django.db import models
from configuracoes.models import Configuracao

# Create your models here.
class Member(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()
    addres = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='members_profile', blank=True, null=True )
    configuracoes = models.ManyToManyField(Configuracao)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} {self.surname}'
```

Porém, apenas isso não basta. Você também precisa implementar no Serializer do usuário o Serializer da configuração. Exemplo:

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
from member.models import Member
from configuracoes.api.serializers import ConfiguracaoSerializer

class MemberSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    configuracoes = ConfiguracaoSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Member
        fields = (
            'id', 'name', 'surname', 'phone', 'email', 'addres', 'photo', 
            'configuracoes'
        )
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Abraços,